# Adding Users programatically in Telnet using java API

Tags: java, telnet

I am using java API to add user in telnet . With the help of the following method I am able to get the data printed on console ...

```
  public void dataReceived(TelnetDataReceivedEvent event) {
        // print data received from telnet server to console
         System.out.print(event.getData());

        }
```

With the help of this code I am getting the following data printed in the console 
................
JAMES Remote Administration Tool 2.3.2
Please enter your login and password
Login id:
Password:
Welcome root. HELP for a list of commands
User demo added
................

It is printing the complete data from the telnet server what I want is it shows only the Last Part i.e prompting for the action like "User demo added" or "User demo exist " ..I don't need the rest of the information , I am quite new to this, did anybody have a idea how to achieve this ???Please help..I am using Jscape for this.

Comment: @Gagravarr No I just want the prompting part when a user is added or exception occured I dont need the rest data i.e. JAMES Remote Administration Tool 2.3.2 Please enter your login and password Login id: Password: Welcome root. HELP for a list of commands....

Comment: I m sorry I might be asking something weird but I am just trying to find If there is any way we can select a part of data to be displayed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print event.getData() directly. Take it into a string and then modify it before printing. You can use the substring function to get the last part.

Probably like this if you are sure about the length of your "Last Part":

```
 public void dataReceived(TelnetDataReceivedEvent event) {

try{
        // print data received from telnet server to console

String s=event.getData();

String final_data=s.substring(s.length()-14);
         System.out.print(final_data.Trim());
}

catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e.message())

}
        }
```

Comment: isn't final a reserved keyword?